# как убрать bom js - php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

как мне убрать bom *

```
      type:"GET",
      url: '../site.php',
      data: 'status=change_login&user='+log+'&password='+password.val()+"&login="+login.val() ,
      success: function(status_login){
        debugger ;  // бедет \ufeff\ufefftrue_login
          console.log(status_login); // бедет true_login 
          if(status_login == "true_login")
          {
            console.log(1);
            $(".button_text_user").text(login.val());
          }else{
            console.log(2);
          }
      }});
```

Comment: Сохранить файл в кодировке `Utf-8 без BOM`

Comment: например как на атом так сделать ?

Comment: там только есть utf-8

Comment: Такой фигнёй не пользуюсь)

Comment: а какой ???????

Comment: если вы на windows, проще всего будет notepad++, там сверху есть меню с кодировкой